# How do I parse a JSON object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have the following function, which currently just displays the object returned from the GET request to the console.  What I need to do is parse the "data" object so that I can return the "output" string from data to my web page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var output = $.ajax({
        url: 'https://ajith-holy-bible.p.mashape.com/GetVerseOfaChapter?Book=John&chapter=3&Verse=16', // The URL to the API. You can get this by clicking on "Show CURL example" from an API profile
        type: 'GET', // The HTTP Method, can be GET POST PUT DELETE etc
        data: {}, // Additional parameters here
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            //
            //Change data.source to data.something , where something is whichever part of the object you want returned.
            //To see the whole object you can output it to your browser console using:
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err);
        },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization", "my_key_here"); // Enter here your Mashape key
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please copy/paste what the returned 'data' object looks like. You can access the different values of the object by using dot-notation on the keys. For example: `data.chapter` = 3, `data.verse` = 16, `data.content` = "(content of verse)"

Comment: I got 403 error .GET https://ajith-holy-bible.p.mashape.com/GetVerseOfaChapter?Book=John&chapter=3&Verse=16 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: If you specify 'dataType' prop as JSOn (which you have) jQuery parses it before passing to callbacks. So 'data' here is an object

Comment: @Cyril This is actually the opposite of what the OP is looking for. The returned data is already a JSON object.

Comment: @BigHeadCreations Here is the output I am getting on the console: Object {Book: "John", Chapter: "3", Verse: "16", Output: "For God had such love for the world that he gave h…ay not come to destruction but have eternal life."}
Book
:
"John"
Chapter
:
"3"
Output
:
"For God had such love for the world that he gave his only Son, so that whoever has faith in him may not come to destruction but have eternal life."
Verse
:
"16"
__proto__
:
Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how your JSON looks like but let's say is

```
{
    "foo": "some value",
    "bar": "some other value"
}
```

then you could do:

```
success: function (data) {

    console.log(data);

    var dataObj = $.parseJSON(data);

    $.each(dataObj, function(key, value) {
        if(key == "foo") {
            // do something with foo's value
            console.log(value);         
        }
        if(key == "bar") {
            // do something with bar's value
            console.log(value); 
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: When I added '            var dataObj = $.parseJSON(data);

            $.each(dataObj, function(key, value) {
                if(key == "Book") {
                    // do something with foo's value
                    console.log(value);
                }
                if(key == "Chapter") {
                    // do something with bar's value
                    console.log(value);
                }
            });
' I got the following:  'VM5861:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1'  and it is showing '[object Object]'

Comment: It looks like for some reason you already have a JavaScript object, so try to remove the line: var dataObj = $.parseJSON(data); and change $.each(dataObj to $.each(data

Comment: That did the trick.  Thank you.  Now I can continue with the rest of my project..

Answer (score 0):

if

```
dataType: 'json',
```

and your response looks like

```
{
   foo:'bar'
}
```

you can just access like

```
    success: function (data) {

     console.log(data.foo)
```

which will output

```
"bar"
```

also it is unnessecary to assign the request to the variable "output"

if this does niot work for you you should json-lint your response, maybe the headers are not correct etc. ...